# Passing an ampersand using window.open()

Tags: javascript, wordpress, window.open

I'm trying to perform this function:

var form = window.open(www.example.com/?param1=' + value1 + '&param2 =' + value2 ,'1_blank', params);

But the problem is, that's opening a new window with the url of:

www.example.com/?param1=XXX#038;param2=YYY

While I need it to open with the url of:

www.example.com/?param1=XXX&param2=YYY

How do I force the ampersand to stay as an ampersand symbol and not get changed to the unicode label?

I'm trying to do this in WordPress, by the way, and am not sure if this is a Wordpress problem is a JS problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using `window.open` with an ampersand sign works fine for me. I think the problem you're having is some special character in your `value1` and `value2`.

So use `encodeURIComponent`. It's built into JavaScript. Use it like this:

```
var form = window.open(www.example.com/?param1=' + encodeURIComponent(value1) + '&param2=' + encodeURIComponent(value2),'1_blank', params);
```

Just a note: you had a space (" ") after `&param2` and right before the equals ("=") sign. This would cause the parameter not to be sent over.

This is a strange problem, so I'm just throwing out an idea. It might just be a browser problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help and insight Sheng. I tried what you suggested and unfortunately it didn't help. However, I'm pretty sure this is a wordpress problem. I'm seeing a lot of people comment on problems with ampersands being converted to &#038 for wordpress titles and posts and such, and I'm starting to think WP also affects the urls. I'm just not sure how to fix it. (P.s that space in the end there was a problem with my typing, not with my code - I didn't copy/paste my code directly, just retyped it. Thanks for pointing out though.)

Comment: @user1608157 Hmmm, then I'm completely baffled. Could you give a link to this problem, perhaps on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are placing your Javascript in the content of your page/post, then Wordpress runs the text through a filter called 'wptexturize'.  This would account for your ampersands being replaced.

If that is the case, you can remove the filter from your theme's functions.php file:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize' );
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: By the way, I do not ever recommend even putting your Javascript in the content of a post.  There are plenty of hooks to add scripts to Wordpress pages.